# JSON Data is not displaying on my listview xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

trying to display only 2 items on my list . I cant get them.The http process is getting the data but I cant display them on the list .

```cs
public class ServiceTypes
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
                         }
    public List<RequestType> GetRequestTypes()
    {
        var list = new List<RequestType>()
        {
            list.Name;
            list.Description;
        };

        return list;           
    }
```

xaml

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Name}">
</ListView>
```

Comment: ItemsSource needs to be an IEnumerable<T> - you are just binding it to a single string property.  And your ListView doesn't have a template.  I'd really suggest you take a few minutes to review the ListView docs.

Comment: as @Jason said you are setting just a string, you have to set  IEnumerable<T> , if you set a simple list of string you don't need a item template, but if you have a list of object you have to create a template for the cell and set the properties for each control.

Comment: so , I changed this.//////public List<ServiceRequestType> GetServiceRequestTypes()
        {
            var list = new List<ServiceRequestType>()
            {
                ServiceRequestType.Name;
                ServiceRequestType.Description;
            };

            return list;
        } /// xaml ///

Comment: Xaml file  looks like .. ./////<ListView   
                        IsPullToRefreshEnabled ="OnRefreshing"
                        ItemTapped = "OnItemTapped"
                        ItemSelected = "OnItemSelected">
              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        
                        <ViewCell>
                         <ViewCell.View>
                         </ViewCell.View>
                     </ViewCell>

                        
                 </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>

Comment: The code that you have posted does not build, and your updates in the comments are unclear (and also are not valid c# code). Try posting the latest version of your valid, buildable code in an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `ItemsSource` property should have a list of the objects that you want to show. Preferably an `ObservableCollection` so changes in your collection are reflected in your `ListView`.

In your code-behind create a property:

`public ObservableCollection<ServiceRequestType> MyList { get; set; }`

And set it somewhere, like in your constructor:

```
public void MyPage()
{
    MyList = new ObservableColletion<ServiceRequestType>();
    MyList.Add(new ServiceRequestType { Name = "Foo" });
    MyList.Add(new ServiceRequestType { Name = "Bar" });

    // I'm setting it to this class, but this could be any class, preferably a ViewModel class
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

Now in your XAML, set your `ItemsSource` to the `MyList` property, like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text = "{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Notice how I also included a `ItemTemplate`. With this you can specify the looks of a cell in your `ListView`. You should also notice that the `Name` property has moved to there.

This means that the `ListView` at the highest level takes properties from the `BindingContext` that the `ListView` is specified on and within the `ListView` the cells have a different scope, namely the scope of the type of object that it in the `ItemsSource`, in our case a `ObservableCollection<ServiceRequestType>` and you can access properties from those types in your cell.

`TextCell` is just one example, there are [multiple types](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/cells/) or you can compose your own.

Comment: My pleasure! Please accept as an answer if it helped!

Comment: I did the binding and add the data template . but Iam still not able to show it on the page.  what I am thinking is some other issue with my viewmodel .because I can see the page title but the list is still not showing

Comment: <ContentPage.Content>
            <Label Margin ="4">  select  </Label>
                 <ListView x:Name = "RequestTypes">
                       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                     <ViewCell>
                      <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                         </ViewCell>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
       </ContentPage.Content>

Comment: List<string> RequestTypesListHeaders = new List<string>
            {
                " Water", "Maintenance", "ing", "Cont ", "zard", " Actty",

            };



        public RequestTypesView()
         {
            InitializeComponent();

            RequestTypes.ItemsSource = RequestTypesHeaders;
         }

Comment: if I hardcode the list it will show , but the idea is get the data from rest . I will show you how I am getting the data . public class ListTypes
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You're not setting the `ItemsSource` on the `ListView`.

Comment: I will post another question , cause I dont have space to paste all I have . I will keep you posted with the new question in a few . thanks GERALD!